# Checking for repetition of any digit at the end of a number?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to check if a digit appears a set amount of times at the end of a number, say 2 times. The regex should probably say something like "group[0-9] 2 times at end", and I could have a PHP variable inserted into the regex indicating the 'amount of repetition', replacing the 2.

What regex expression should I use?

P.S: Hopefully this snippet of [PHP code](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) can help verify if the expression, which should check if any digit is repeated **2** times at the end of a number, is correct.

```
$Regex="/$[help]$/";
$Input=array(123456,112345,333333,123455,99);
$CorrectOutput=array(0,0,0,1,1);

echo "==WORKING IN EVERY TEST CASE?==<br>";

for($TestEntry=0;$TestEntry<=4;$TestEntry++){
    $Result = preg_match($Regex,$Input[$TestEntry]);
    if($Result==$CorrectOutput[$TestEntry]){
        echo "Got ".$Result.", expected ".$CorrectOutput[$TestEntry]." - Good, seems to be working for " . $Input[$TestEntry] . ".<br>";
    }else{
        echo "Got ".$Result.", expected ".$CorrectOutput[$TestEntry]." - Sorry, not working for " . $Input[$TestEntry] . ".<br>";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

*Answer is most probably the following, thanks a lot:*

```
$Repetition = 3; //Number of times a digit repeats at the end of the number (min. 2)
$Regex='/(?:^(\d)\1{'.($Repetition-1).'}$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{'.$Repetition.'})(\d)\3{'.($Repetition-1).'}$)/';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried many times and finally get it to work:

```
$Regex="/(^|.)(^|(?!\\1))(.)\\3$/";
```

Passed all your test cases :)

Comment: Wow, certainly looks impressive! I still get "Sorry, not working for 123455." and "Sorry, not working for 99." when using it, though, hmm..

Comment: That's because the site you tested on are taking something wrong in " and \, I run this code on my own machine using php cli is getting correct answer, and you should change " to ' on that site so that you would get all 5 correct too :) ( e.g. `$Regex='/(^|.)(^|(?!\\1))(.)\\3$/';` on that site.)

Comment: Not a clue how you ever found out about that, but you're right! Working beautifully now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one , it's simple and easy to analyzing

```
$Regex='/(?:^(\\d)\\1$)|(?:^.*(\\d)(?!\\2{2})(\\d)\\3$)/';
```

But, this code is only for the site you give(http://writecodeonline.com/php/). the origin regex is

```
(?:^(\d)\1$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{2})(\d)\3$)
```

Comment: Alright, in what way should I change it to look for 3, 4, 5 or more repetitions instead of just 2? Should I just change the {2}? (Edit: Just tried doing that, didn't seem to work)

Comment: You need this one instead of it:(?:^(\d)\1{1}$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{2})(\d)\3{2}$)， the number in {} you need change it

Comment: Which one? There's nothing after the : it seems.

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to match more than 2 using the regex in my post, just add `{2}` after \\3 to match 3, or `{3}` to match 4, etc.

Comment: You should notice double quote and single quote. In php, double quote will escape the string

Comment: But '/(?:^(\\d)\\1$)|(?:^.*(\\d)(?!\\2{2})(\\d)\\3{2}$)/' (added the {2} to match 3 repetitions, like you said) still matches '99' for some reason.

Comment: You need change three number, for example, if you want match 3 repetitions, you need this `(?:^(\d)\1{2}$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{3})(\d)\3{2}$)`, if you want match 4 repetitions, you need this `(?:^(\d)\1{3}$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{4})(\d)\3{3}$)`. maybe `(?:^(\d)\1{1}$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2\2{1})(\d)\3{1}$)` can explain the repetitions

Comment: Ah I get it, for N repetitions, it should be:
(?:^(\d)\1{ (N-1) }$)|(?:^.*(\d)(?!\2{ N })(\d)\3{ (N-1) }$)

Answer (score -1):

This regexp catches 2 or more 9's at the end of a string:

```
9{2,}\Z
```

The 9 is what to look for, {2,} means "two or more times" and \Z tells to look only at the end of a string.

Maybe this will help you get started.

This would concretely look like:

```
<?php
$subject = "12389798712899";
$pattern = '/9{2,}\Z/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This should print an array $matches that has one element, i.e. the searched expression was found one time.

And to use the expression in your test case you'd use a number range, as you are testing against any single digit number:

```
$Regex='/[0-9]{2,}\Z/';
```

Comment: Tried [0-9]{2}\Z ,but that didn't work either, unfortunately. Could you please explain what's wrong?

Comment: Because it only guarantees the two chars at ending are both matching [0-9], and that's surely true for all your test cases :)